# Elm Current Date

Tags: date, elm

In elm I have a model that includes a `currentDate`, it's a string representing the date. I update it with a signal:

```
Signal.map (SetCurrentDate << timeToDateString) (Time.every Time.second)
```

`SetCurrentDate`is an action that updates the model (`SetCurrentDate date -> { model | currentDate <- date}`), and `timeToDateString` converts from time to a string like "yyyy-mm-dd".

However, there are two problems with this:

- `model.currentDate` is only correctly set after one second. So there's a second at the start of the app where the currentDate is not properly set.
- `model.currentDate` is set every second, even though it only changes every day.

Is there a way to fix this? So the currentDate is set at the start of the app (without the one second delay), and that it's only updated one a day?

Extra findings:

If I change the signal to `Signal.dropRepeats <| Signal.map (SetCurrentDate << timeToDateString) (Time.every Time.second)` (so I drop the repeats), the signal is only fired when the day changes, and not also once on the start of the app.

Edit: If there is a better way of knowing the currentDate in an Elm application, I would love to hear it. My Googling gave nothing.

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get the current time in Elm 0.17/0.18?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38021777/how-do-i-get-the-current-time-in-elm-0-17-0-18)

Comment: @rofrol This question was asked when Elm 0.16 was the latest. However, for current versions it is indeed the same question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Using Signals

Are you using `StartApp` or do you have your own `foldp`? If you are using `StartApp` it's best to look up the code for the `start` function and inline it so you have access to the `foldp`.

`Signal.foldp` doesn't do anything with the initial value of a signal. So if you use the `Time.every second` signal, you only get your update after a second, and only after a day if you use the date conversion and `Signal.dropRepeats`. You can use [`Signal.Extra.foldp'`](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/Apanatshka/elm-signal-extra/5.7.0/Signal-Extra#foldp') from the 3rd party [signal-extra](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/Apanatshka/elm-signal-extra/) library* to fix that. It takes a function to create the initial state of the `foldp` from the initial value of the input.

*Full disclosure: I'm the author of the library

## Using Tasks

There is a very useful task in the [task-tutorial](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/evancz/task-tutorial/1.0.3/) library called [`getCurrentTime`](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/evancz/task-tutorial/1.0.3/TaskTutorial#getCurrentTime). I think that can serve your needs without needing a signal that updates every second. Along with [`Task.sleep`](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/core/3.0.0/Task#sleep), you can probably get something that only checks the time once or twice a day.

Comment: This seems to work very nicely. Thanks a lot for the very clear answer!

Comment: I ended up using the `getCurrentTime` from the tutorial too as it works nicely with the Elm StartApp. I really would like to see something similar in the Elm stdlib. Took me quite a while to figure this out.

Answer (score 1):

Apanatshka's answer ([and](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29453679/how-do-i-get-the-current-time-in-elm/29454481#29454481) [others](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28606248/what-is-the-correct-way-of-initializing-an-elm-application/28616836#28616836)) made sense, but as a beginner to Elm I had trouble applying the explanation to actual code. After some fuddling around, here is a minimal amount of code needed to render an auto-updating date (using Elm v0.16.0):

```
import Signal
import Html exposing (Html, text)
import Time exposing (Time, every)
import Date exposing (Date, Month, fromTime, year, month, day, hour, minute, second)

-- not used by foldp (https://stackoverflow.com/a/34095298/480608)
startTime = 0

type Action = Update Date

type alias Model = Date

showDate : Date -> String
showDate date = toString (month date) ++ " " ++
  toString (day date) ++ ", " ++
  toString (year date) ++ "  " ++
  toString (hour date) ++ ":" ++
  toString (minute date) ++ ":" ++
  toString (second date)

update : Action -> Model -> Model
update (Update date) _ = date

model : Signal Model
model =
  Signal.foldp update (fromTime startTime) clock

timeToAction : Time -> Action
timeToAction time = Update <| fromTime time

clock : Signal Action
clock =
  Signal.map timeToAction <| every Time.second

main : Signal Html
main =
  Signal.map view model

view : Model -> Html
view model =
  text <| showDate model
```

Here's a slightly more complex example that merges the clock into other signals. No idea how well this conforms to elm best practices, but it works, and it may serve as a helpful learning tool as it did for me.

```
import Signal
import Html exposing (..)
import Html.Events exposing (..)
import Keyboard
import Char
import Time exposing (Time)
import Date exposing (Date, Month, fromTime, year, month, day, hour, minute, second)

startTime = 0

type Action =
  NoOp
  | Increment
  | Decrement
  | Update Time

type alias Model = {
  count: Int,
  time: Time
}

showDate : Date -> String
showDate date = toString (month date) ++ " " ++
  toString (day date) ++ ", " ++
  toString (year date) ++ "  " ++
  toString (hour date) ++ ":" ++
  toString (minute date) ++ ":" ++
  toString (second date)

actions : Signal.Mailbox Action
actions =
  Signal.mailbox NoOp

update : Action -> Model -> Model
update action model =
  case action of
    NoOp -> model
    Increment -> { model | count = model.count + 1 }
    Decrement -> { model | count = model.count - 1 }
    Update time -> { model | time = time }

model : Signal Model
model =
  Signal.foldp update { count = 0, time = startTime } (Signal.mergeMany [
    actions.signal,
    keyPressesToAction,
    clock
  ])

keyPressesToAction : Signal Action
keyPressesToAction =
  let
    keyCodeToAction keyCode =
      case Char.fromCode keyCode of
        '=' -> Increment
        '-' -> Decrement
        _ -> NoOp
  in
    Signal.map keyCodeToAction Keyboard.presses

timeToAction : Time -> Action
timeToAction time = Update time

clock : Signal Action
clock = Signal.map timeToAction (Time.every Time.second)

main : Signal Html
main =
  Signal.map (view actions.address) model

view : Signal.Address Action -> Model -> Html
view address model =
  div [] [
    text <| showDate <| fromTime model.time,
    div []
      [ button [ onClick address Decrement ] [ text "-" ]
      , text <| toString model.count
      , button [ onClick address Increment ] [ text "+" ]
      ]
  ]
```

Comment: @z5h made a version of StartUp that passes the time to update: https://gist.github.com/z5h/41ca436679591b6c3e51